Band pass filter zero crossing distortion

Second stage output

Drawing
I built the above bandpass filter using lag lead combination for filtering +/-2.5 Vp-p square wave @ 125 kHz, but the extracted sine wave have zero crossing distortion,tested at another frequency @ 64 kHz using suitable capacitor value, zero crossing distortion exists at that frequency also. I used TL084 (though it is class AB only) for a guess I tried TL074 instead, problem prevails. What do I need to correct? Please suggest.
Update-21/4/23
Able to attain much better selectivity by replacing the feedback resistor from second stage to first stage input by a smaller resistance,and making the  filter resistor variable able to tune it properly.
Update -22/4/23
Able to obtain filtered sine for most frequency of interest. Attached is an output.

Though by trial and error I achieved the output,I don't fully understand the circuit.
I have the following questions

how to quantify the effect of feedback resistor from stage 2 to stage 1 input

the phase relationship between square and sine is slowly drifting with time,how can I stabilize this.i am having some difficulty to tune to point where this zero drift,if it is achieved also sine and square are not in phase.

if point 2 is achieved,circuit being Q multiplier ,how can I stabilize the output in case this circuit operating at varying temperature,in that case I have to manually adjust the filter values every now then,can i use a feedback through synchronous demodulation and tune the circuit(using digital potentiometer)so that 90° quadrature output is close to zero.


For point 3 is there full analog method because I will be having some 10 channels of output with varying frequency a band pass filter for each channel,in that  case digipot cost rise rapidly and also cumbersome to handle with microcontroller.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Re your latest edit: did you use caps with large temperature coefficient like X7R ceramics? Or low tempco (C0G ceramic, film...)

I am using polyester film for some and metallized polypropylene  for some.

There are 6th and 8th order integrated circuit filters with very good performance for your frequency range. They are programmed by a clock input, and thus very stable. Most linear IC vendors have them. Analog Devices has both Linear Technology and Maxim parts.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I considered them but most of the implementation I saw was low pass filter,my requirement was bandpass,so I didn't want to dig any deeper as I had no prior experience using them.is bandpass filter possible with 8th order elliptic filter IC's?

Made with microcap v12.
As already pointed, use supply capacitors "directly" on the supply pins of the opamp ...
Short wires and "nearest" capacitors are wired. (V3 is "triangular" ...)

Update: remaked simulation showing all signals.
Distortion present probably caused by "delays" in the flow of signals (double retroaction).

For example, here is the behavior at a lower input frequency.
This explains why this circuit is not a second order filter.


Thankyou. As it was Q-multiplying it is highly selective,so once proper filter values are selected,i though no more optimization is needed,so didn't do any simulation. Besides as bobflux pointed out Opamp model is ideal is very simple in simulation software need some tinkering to show the practical non idealities.

In your simulation positive and negative peaks seems to be bit distorted or is it a display artifact ?like earlier said i still suspect the tolerance of components used. I will make one filter element variable and update the results.

Yes, it is distorted ... I changed for some opamps (faster than TL082c) and distortion is always present. Will try with DC Analysis ...

Any suggestion for improvement.As I will go to bench tomorrow only,I will try in simulation before that,as my idea is all about varying the filter resistor value

In your update low frequency response the harmonic of the fundamental frequency is selectively amplified.power level of 5 th harmonic in 1/5 with positive feedback get additively added with input .2/5 equals approximately 1 Vp-p,100nf to 1uf capacitor in parallel with global feed back resistor(2nd stage to 1st)reduce these distortion well enough for practical use.

Difficult to wrap my head around with out some quantitative analysis,as there is phase shifted version get added additively,they produce weird waveforms.

You'll have more luck with a Wien bridge instead. One op-amp will do it, and it will be quite stable. See e.g. Larry Lisle's The Audio Q Multiplier.
In your lead-lag circuit, the op amps must cope with full bandwidth of the square wave. The op-amps don't slew fast enough it looks like.
The lead-lag design can be made to work well, but the circuit topology will be a bit different. I'll have to experiment a bit to come up with something workable. It won't be very practical for multiple channels of course - who has the time to tune all that. And you'd need good brand, low tempco resistors, and good capacitors, from mainstream distributors like DigiKey, Mouser, etc. If your resistors and capacitors didn't came from somewhere else, they may well be very poor quality. You'd have to measure their performance separately. You'll likely find that they are not good at all. If the resistors or capacitors have any ferromagnetic parts, i.e. anything that is attracted by a magnet, you can throw them out right away - they are cheap trash.
There are 6th and 8th order integrated circuit filters with very good performance for your frequency range. They are programmed by a clock input, and thus very stable. Most linear IC vendors have them. Analog Devices has both Linear Technology and Maxim parts. They may be more expensive, but your time is expensive too. The various clock frequencies can be generated with a microcontroller, a CPLD or a tiny FPGA, or a discrete logic divider network, etc. It will be the most dependable and easiest to implement solution.

You are right about slew rate of opamp,for lower frequencies the circuit seems to have less distortion,higher order harmonics are easily cancelled,once I go above certain frequencies distortion come in.i have planned this method so that I can have master clock,derive all the sub frequency by divider and filter them out ,additively combine as multi frequency excitation  for sensor, then use the individual square wave for synchronous demodulation of received signals,now wheels seems to be coming off,as I didn't have a plan b

@dhuwarkesh You can still do it that way. The filter ICs typically need the filter center frequency multiplied by some constant like 50 or 100 - usually a multiple of 10, sometimes a power of 2 (see datasheet). So, if you have a 1kHz clock and 100kHz clock, feed the 1kHz square to filter's signal input, 100kHz square to filter's clock input, and you'll get a 1kHz sine on the output. Easy! The filters are configured for low/band/highpass by strapping the pins in a certain way usually, and they require no external components other than a supply bypass capacitor. They are really fun to work with.
